# How can I manually set a focus area in Android?

Tags: android, camera, focus, setfocus

I have built a small camera app for android. Now I would like to know how I can tell my app (or better tell the camera)  that it should focus on say the upper left corner of my preview.

How can I do that? Which methods can I use to set the focus on the upper left corner? From the documentation I know, that there is a method `setFocusAreas()`. But I don't feel that that is very helpful for my problem.

Any ideas?